# Compare two xpath_node_set in C++ with pugixml 1.4

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, pugixml

I have two XML files and I want to compare a subsection of it if it is equal. 
The XML files can be very different but I give an example.
I have following XML files:

```
<EXECUTION_SET>
  <RESULT query_id="7" >
    <OP>
      <PROJ>
        <COLUMN col_name="City.ID" col_type="3" col_length="11" />
        <OP>
          <JOIN>
            <OP>
              <TABLE name="City" alias="City" access_type="5" total_record_length="67">
                <COLUMN col_name="ID" col_type="3" col_length="11" raw_length="4" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Name" col_type="254" col_length="35" raw_length="35" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="CountryCode" col_type="254" col_length="3" raw_length="3" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="District" col_type="254" col_length="20" raw_length="20" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Population" col_type="3" col_length="11" raw_length="4" /> 
              </TABLE>
            </OP>
            <OP>
              <SEL>
                <COND>
                  <COND>
                    <VALUE><VARIABLE>Country.Population</VARIABLE></VALUE>
                  </COND>
                  <BOP><![CDATA[>]]></BOP>
                  <COND>
                    <VALUE><CONSTANT>80000000</CONSTANT></VALUE>
                  </COND>
                </COND>
                <OP>
                <OP>
                  <TABLE name="Country" alias="Country" access_type="5" total_record_length="261">
                    <COLUMN col_name="Code" col_type="254" col_length="3" raw_length="3" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="Name" col_type="254" col_length="52" raw_length="52" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="Continent" col_type="254" col_length="13" raw_length="1" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="Region" col_type="254" col_length="26" raw_length="26" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="SurfaceArea" col_type="4" col_length="10" raw_length="4" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="IndepYear" col_type="2" col_length="6" raw_length="2" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="Population" col_type="3" col_length="11" raw_length="4" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="LifeExpectancy" col_type="4" col_length="3" raw_length="4" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="GNP" col_type="4" col_length="10" raw_length="4" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="GNPOld" col_type="4" col_length="10" raw_length="4" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="LocalName" col_type="254" col_length="45" raw_length="45" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="GovernmentForm" col_type="254" col_length="45" raw_length="45" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="HeadOfState" col_type="254" col_length="60" raw_length="60" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="Capital" col_type="3" col_length="11" raw_length="4" /> 
                    <COLUMN col_name="Code2" col_type="254" col_length="2" raw_length="2" /> 
                  </TABLE>
                </OP>
                </OP>
              </SEL>
            </OP>
          </JOIN>
        </OP>
      </PROJ>
    </OP>
  </RESULT>
</EXECUTION_SET>
```

And the second XML file:

```
<EXECUTION_SET>
  <RESULT query_id="13" >
    <OP>
      <PROJ>
        <COLUMN col_name="Country.Code" col_type="254" col_length="3" />
        <OP>
          <SEL>
            <COND>
              <COND>
                <VALUE><VARIABLE>Country.Population</VARIABLE></VALUE>
              </COND>
              <BOP><![CDATA[>]]></BOP>
              <COND>
                <VALUE><CONSTANT>80000000</CONSTANT></VALUE>
              </COND>
            </COND>
            <OP>
            <OP>
              <TABLE name="Country" alias="Country" access_type="5" total_record_length="261">
                <COLUMN col_name="Code" col_type="254" col_length="3" raw_length="3" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Name" col_type="254" col_length="52" raw_length="52" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Continent" col_type="254" col_length="13" raw_length="1" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Region" col_type="254" col_length="26" raw_length="26" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="SurfaceArea" col_type="4" col_length="10" raw_length="4" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="IndepYear" col_type="2" col_length="6" raw_length="2" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Population" col_type="3" col_length="11" raw_length="4" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="LifeExpectancy" col_type="4" col_length="3" raw_length="4" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="GNP" col_type="4" col_length="10" raw_length="4" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="GNPOld" col_type="4" col_length="10" raw_length="4" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="LocalName" col_type="254" col_length="45" raw_length="45" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="GovernmentForm" col_type="254" col_length="45" raw_length="45" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="HeadOfState" col_type="254" col_length="60" raw_length="60" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Capital" col_type="3" col_length="11" raw_length="4" /> 
                <COLUMN col_name="Code2" col_type="254" col_length="2" raw_length="2" /> 
              </TABLE>
            </OP>
            </OP>
          </SEL>
        </OP>
      </PROJ>
    </OP>
  </RESULT>
</EXECUTION_SET>
```

With this two XML files, I want to compare the subsection under the  tag if this subsection is equal. For that I do for both xpath queries following: `doc.select_nodes(std::string("//TABLE[@name='Country']/ancestor::SEL/COND").c_str());` and write it in the variables `pugi::xpath_node_set partialTree1` and `partialTree2`.

So I get the subsections of both xml files. Now I want to compare both subsections. It should be a good efficient way.

I have a solution but I don't like it because it needs to much time and space. At the moment I use the `traverse` function to go throw the subsections and write all in a string for both subsections. Then I compare it. But there must be a better way for that.

Would be nice if someone have some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a result of your query, you have a set of nodes from different documents. Each node has a certain amount of descendants, and to compare two nodes you have to compare all of their descendants - if you miss one you don't know whether the trees are equal.

This suggests that the approach of comparing the string dump of the nodes is optimal complexity-wise in terms of time. It is not optimal in terms of space - an optimal algorithm in terms of space goes through both trees in sync and compares values directly. Something like this should work:

```
template <typename It, typename Pred>
bool rangeEquals(It lb, It le, It rb, It re, Pred pred)
{
    It li = lb, ri = rb;

    for (; li != le && ri != re; ++li, ++ri)
        if (!pred(*li, *ri))
            return false;

    return li == le && ri == re;
}

bool attrEquals(pugi::xml_attribute la, pugi::xml_attribute ra)
{
    return
        strcmp(la.name(), ra.name()) == 0 &&
        strcmp(la.value(), ra.value()) == 0;
}

bool nodeEquals(pugi::xml_node ln, pugi::xml_node rn)
{
    return
        ln.type() == rn.type() &&
        strcmp(ln.name(), rn.name()) == 0 &&
        strcmp(ln.value(), rn.value()) == 0 &&
        rangeEquals(ln.attributes_begin(), ln.attributes_end(), rn.attributes_begin(), rn.attributes_end(), attrEquals) &&
        rangeEquals(ln.begin(), ln.end(), rn.begin(), rn.end(), nodeEquals);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hoped that there will be a better way, but so I know what to do :)